# Testing sagas: Stubbing response from a call effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have the following saga:

```
export function* getPosts() {
  try {
    const response = yield call(apiCall);
    yield put({ type: "API_CALL_SUCCESS", response });
  } catch(e) {
    // ...
  }
```

and the following spec:

```
describe('GetPosts', () => { 
  beforeEach(() => {
    sinon.stub(api, 'apiCall').returns(Promise.resolve({some:'value'}));
  });


  const generator = getPosts();
  it('should yield call', () => {
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(api.apiCall));
  });

  it('should yield put', () => {
    expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(put({ type: "API_CALL_SUCCESS", response: { some: 'value' } }));
  });
});
```

The first test passes but the second one fails because it expects response to equal `{some: 'value'}` but it's actually `undefined` even though the stub is set to return a resolved promise with the value of `{some: 'value'}`.

Why is this and what is the correct way to test this code?

Answer (score 0):

Worked this out. Should have used an action creator instead:

```
export function* getPosts() {
  try {
    const res = yield call(someCall);
    yield put(actions.receive(res));
  } catch(e) {
    // ...
  }
```

tested like so:

```
it('should yield put', () => {
    const data = {}
    expect(gen.next(thing).value).toEqual(put(actions.receive(data)));
  });
```